# Arcgis Javascript Dynamically Show infoWindow for Polylines

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am working on a web map using ArcGIS Javascript API and am having issues when showing infoWindow for polylines.  What I am trying to do is to dynamically show infoWindow after a selectFeatures is performed.  Basically I have it set up where feature is selected and the map zooms to that feature location and I have the infoWindow pop up for that feature.  I have it working fine for points and polygons but I can't seem to get it working for polylines.  I have been able to successfully get the infoWindow to show up but not in the desired location.  I can get it to show up in the upper left corner (using map.infoWindow.show();) or in the center of the extent of the polyline (using map.infoWindow.show(features[0].geometry.getExtent().getCenter();).  But the latter of those two is usually not actually pointing to the line and in the middle of nowhere since it is using the extent.  I have also used the path points of the features and getting the midpoint that way.  This was the closest I got to success, but the infoWindow never showed up in the viewspace and would be half shown or a quarter shown - requiring the user to pan in order to see it.  Does anyone know how I can fix this to work better in the way I want it to?  See code snippet below for the area where I perform this in my script (the else statement is meant for polylines).

Code Snippet:

```
if (features[0].geometry.type == "point"){
    map.centerAndZoom(features[0].geometry, map.getMaxZoom()+2);
    var center = features[0].geometry;
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures(features);
    map.infoWindow.show(center); 
}else if (features[0].geometry.type == "polygon"){
    var lyrExtent = features[0].geometry.getExtent().expand(2.0);
    var center = features[0].geometry.getCentroid();
    map.setExtent(lyrExtent);
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures(features); 
    map.infoWindow.show(center); 
}else{
    var lyrExtent = features[0].geometry.getExtent().expand(2.0);
    var center = features[0].geometry.getExtent().getCenter();
    var centerCoords = features[0].geometry.paths[0][features[0].geometry.paths[0].length/2];
    var centerPt = new Point(centerCoords, map.spatialReference);
    map.setExtent(lyrExtent);
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures(features); 
    map.infoWindow.show(center); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will have to write custom code to re-set the extent so the pop up is visible. You can see [an example in the Bootstrap Map source code](https://github.com/Esri/bootstrap-map-js/blob/master/src/js/bootstrapmap.js#L360-L399). You can probably include that library and use it to instantiate your map and get that behavior for free - even if you're not using Bootstrap.

Alternatively, you could use the the [extent's `expand()` method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html#expand) to force it to zoom out by some factor.